# I need a Google Formula that counts cells that meet two conditions in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I am running reports on. I need to count some data within the `B` column. The data is within the same column on the same sheet tab.

This formula below looks in the `B` column and counts `C`.

`=COUNTIF('Google Sheet Tab1'!B1:B1071,"C")`

This didn't work either

`=COUNTIFS(Google Sheet Tab1!B1:B1071,"C",Google Sheet Tab1!B1:B1071,"N")`

I need a formula that looks for `C` and `N` and adds them together and displays them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add both conditions.
Please try

```
=COUNTIF('Google Sheet Tab1'!B1:B1071,"C")+COUNTIF('Google Sheet Tab1'!B1:B1071,"N")
```

`COUNTIFS` would need to satisfy both conditions at the same time.

Read more [about it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550).